# VS2015 Go to Definition in referenced assembly not working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I have 2 solutions open (2 VS2015 instances) and build both in Debug. Solution "B" references build assemblies from Solution "A" (symbol files are present).

When I try to step through code in Solution "B" and Go to Definition for a class that is defined in Solution "A", I get:

[image]

When I open Solution "B" in VS**2013** instead, everything works as expected and  I can go to the definition of a class in a referenced assembly.

Any idea how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest Update of Visual Studio this should be fixed:

[VisualStudio 2015 Update 1RC](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs)